# 2 dimensional list sorting python 3.6.1 anaconda

Tags: python, web-scraping, anaconda, python-3.6

```
lijst = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
         [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
         [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/oracle-plsql-ontwikkelaar-1/'], [], [], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/oracle-plsql-ontwikkelaar-1/'],
         ['/vacatures/business-intelligence-developer-1/'], [], [], [], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/business-intelligence-developer-1/'],
         ['/vacatures/oracle-dba/'], [], [], ['/vacatures/oracle-dba/'],
         ['/vacatures/database-beheerder/'], [], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/database-beheerder/'],
         ['/vacatures/sql-server-dba-powershell/'], [], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/sql-server-dba-powershell/'],
         ['/vacatures/junior-msbi-consultant/'], [], [], [], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/junior-msbi-consultant/'],
         ['/vacatures/senior-msbi-consultant/'], [], [], [], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/senior-msbi-consultant/'],
         ['/vacatures/medior-msbi-consultant/'], [], [], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/medior-msbi-consultant/'],
         ['/vacatures/zos-mainframe-specialist/'], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/zos-mainframe-specialist/'],
         ['/vacatures/junior-business-analyst/'], [], [], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/junior-business-analyst/'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
         [], ['/vacatures/oracle-plsql-ontwikkelaar-1/'], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/oracle-dba/'], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/business-intelligence-developer-1/'], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/database-beheerder/'], [], [],
         ['/vacatures/sql-server-dba-powershell/'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
         [], [], []]
```

I have a question. How can I filter out the empty lists and remove the duplicate items inside of the 2 dimensional list?

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: @EricDuminil In case the OP wants to make it flat ?

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as doing

```
new_list0 = list(filter(len, lijst))
```

and then to remove duplicate, you could turn `new_list` into `set` and then cast it back to a list. As follows

```
new_list1 = list(set(tuple(x) for x in new_list0))
```

And if you want to cast the elements of `new_list1` (that are tuple now) back to lists, something you can do is

```
new_list2 = list(map(list, new_list1))
```

---

But, given the number of back and forth performed above(casting from generator, to list, to set, ..., to list, and so on), something which *appears* better in term of performance is probably

```
new_list = []
for el in lijst:
    if el and el not in new_list:
        new_list.append(el)            
#print(new_list)
```

---

Finally, note that `new_list` will still be 2-dimensional, as the original one. If you want to make it 1-dimensional, something you can do is [making it flat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python), as follows

```
import itertools
new_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(new_list))
```

or directly creating it as a 1-dimensional list and reducing the time complexity to `O(n)` (instead of `O(n**2)` by avoiding the `in` operator)

```
new_set = set()
for el in lijst:
    if el:
        new_set.update(el)        
new_list = list(new_set)
```

---

*answer tested and functional*

Comment: This will result in `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

Comment: Looks good. If necessary you can cast the inner tuples back to lists.

Comment: Also, your unique examples are `O(n**2)`, even though they could be `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks @EricDuminil.

Answer (score 2):

Your list isn't really 2 dimensional. Every list has either 0 or 1 element.

In that case, you could just extract the strings and put them into a set:

```
print({l[0] for l in lijst if l})
```

It outputs:

```
set(['/vacatures/junior-msbi-consultant/', '/vacatures/junior-business-analyst/', '/vacatures/business-intelligence-developer-1/', '/vacatures/zos-mainframe-specialist/', '/vacatures/sql-server-dba-powershell/', '/vacatures/database-beheerder/', '/vacatures/medior-msbi-consultant/', '/vacatures/oracle-dba/', '/vacatures/oracle-plsql-ontwikkelaar-1/', '/vacatures/senior-msbi-consultant/'])
```

It's concise and fast (`O(n)`).

Comment: Clearly better than my answer. Except that it does not work if the OP wants to keep the final output as a (not-really) 2d list.. which is not likely however.